# Extracting the order in which elements were entered to a binary search tree

Tags: binary-search-tree

Is there a way, theoretically, to extract the order in which numbers were originally entered into a binary search tree ? As in, a method besides one of the normal traversals to find the order that the numbers were inputted?

Comment: Not unless you record that order somehow.

Comment: Probably, the only way is to maintain separate list with synchronized insertions and deletions.

Comment: By definition I would say no.  However if you think in terms of pointers it is possible that the memory address of each item is in effect an order of insertion by memory address if you had a well-known memory allocation mechanism, such as a pre allocated nodes in sequence and attached them.  I would by definition never trust such a mechanism except forensically for a theoretical discussion.